# Docker Compose does not restart dependable containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, synology

I'm not sure if I correctly understand how the "restart" option works in docker.

Below is an example from a docker compose file. What happens is:

1. Docker starts both containers simultaneously.
2. gluetun container takes may be 15-20 seconds to establish connection
3. during this 15-20 seconds linuxserver-deluge starts, sees that it cannot connect to network and shuts down.
4. gluetun container runs
5. linuxserver-deluge stands still with the status Stopped and some error, either 128 or 137.

I would expect, that Docker try to restart the linuxserver-deluge until it manage to connect to the network.

My question is, why Docker doesn't restart linuxserver-deluge container. And what can I do to either let the second container wait for the first one, or force Docker to restart second container in the loop.

If it matters the whole thing runs on Synology DSM 7.1 and managed by Portainer.

```
version: "3"
services:
**  gluetun:**
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun
    container_name: gluetun_vpn
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=some provider
      - ... other variables
    ports: #uncomment ports below for additional applications
      - ... port mapping 
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/gluetun:/gluetun
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: unless-stopped

  linuxserver-deluge:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/deluge
    container_name: deluge_gluetun
**    network_mode: service:gluetun # run on the vpn network**
    environment:
      - ... env variables
    volumes:
      - ... folder mapping
**    restart: always   **
```

I have tried to adjust the compose file with depend_on option, but it seems to have no impact on issue.

Here

```
version: "3"
services:
  gluetun:
    image: qmcgaw/gluetun
    container_name: gluetun_vpn
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - VPN_SERVICE_PROVIDER=some provider
      - ... other variables
    ports: #uncomment ports below for additional applications
      - ... port mapping 
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/gluetun:/gluetun
    network_mode: bridge
    restart: unless-stopped

  linuxserver-deluge:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/deluge
    container_name: deluge_gluetun
    network_mode: service:gluetun # run on the vpn network
    environment:
      - ... env variables
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/deluge:/config
      - /volume1/Downloads:/data/torrents
**    depends_on:
      - gluetun**
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1):

`depends_on` does not restart dependent services. That is not its purpose. Its purpose is to WAIT for the dependent services to start up initially, so the condition for dependence is met

> depends_on expresses startup and shutdown dependencies between services.

> Compose implementations MUST guarantee dependency services have been started before starting a dependent service. Compose implementations MAY wait for dependency services to be “ready” before starting a dependent service.

from https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#depends_on

Comment: Note that the standard behavior of `depends_on:` is only that the other container exists; in the description where it takes 15-20 seconds for the container to become functional, `depends_on:` on its own won't wait for this.